# optional to optional relationship in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Could someone guide me to the use of model builder in this scenario. I tried something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasOptional(f => f.Employee)
        .WithOptionalPrincipal(e => e.User);

public class User 
{
       public int UserID {get; set;}
       public virtual Employee employee{get; set;}
}
public class Employee 
{
       public int EmployeeID {get; set;}
       public int UserID {get; set;}
       public virtual User user {get; set;}
}
```

It does not fetch employee data.

Comment: I think there is no optional to optional relationship, Principal may have optional Dependent, but Dependent requires existing Principal to refer to. Unless it's a one to many relationship where Dependent may have optional Principal. But in one to one-or-zero relationship, I'm afraid such relationship (opt to opt) doesn't exist.

Comment: any other way to get around it ?

Answer (score 0):

The work around for your requirement would be creating one to many relationship with independent association.

```
public class User // Principal
{
    public int UserID { get; set; } // PK
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
public class Employee // Dependent
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; } // PK
    // public int UserID {get; set; } // remove to create independent association
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Config

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasOptional(u => u.Employee)
    .WithOptionalPrincipal(e => e.User);
```

The generated database will create one to many relationship. User becomes Principal and Employee becomes Dependent, but Employee can have optional Principal.

```
using (var db = new AppContext())
{
    // User can have optional Employee.
    db.Users.Add(new User { UserID = 1, Employee = null });
    db.SaveChanges();
}
using (var db = new AppContext())
{
    // Employee can have optional User.
    db.Employees.Add(new Employee { EmployeeID = 1, User = null });
    db.Employees.Add(new Employee { EmployeeID = 2, User = null });
    db.SaveChanges();
}

 User            Employee
------     ----------------------
UserID     EmployeeID User_UserID
  1            1         null
               2         null
```

Relate Employee(1) with User(1).

```
using (var db = new AppContext())
{
    var employee = db.Employees.Find(1);
    employee.User = db.Users.Find(1);
    db.SaveChanges();
}

 User            Employee
------     ----------------------
UserID     EmployeeID User_UserID
  1            1          1
               2         null
```

Relate Employee(2) with User(1).

```
using (var db = new AppContext())
{
    var employee = db.Employees.Find(2);
    employee.User = db.Users.Find(1);
    db.SaveChanges();
}

 User            Employee
------     ----------------------
UserID     EmployeeID User_UserID
  1            1         null
               2          1
```

Of course if we manually change it from database, it will work, but there might be unexpected behavior on EF after it's executed.

```
update Employees set User_UserId = 1
```